# retrieve posts from user's friends having only a row for each friendship

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have this 3 tables:

```
POST (id, name, id_user, ..)
FRIENDS (id, followerid, followingid, acepted) /* acepted must be 1 to users be considered friends */
```

OK, so i wanted to get all friend's posts from user 5. but i am having a lot of trouble constructing the query. i know i need to JOIN, the problem is that the current user (with id 5) could be followerid or followingid, so how could i know?

I was trying someting like (but got blocked with the nonsenseness):

```
SELECT posts.*,friends.id 
                    FROM friends LEFT JOIN ON (friends.followerid  = posts.id) OR (friends.following.id = posts.id)
```

But i don't really know if ON accepts OR inside, can i get some hint here? thanks!

Comment: Can the same pair of users be added twice to `FRIENDS` (as `A, B` and as `B, A`)? If so, can one of the rows have `acepted = 1` and the other `acepted = 0`? If so, should `B` be returned as a friend of `A` (or `A` as a friend of `B` for that matter)?

Comment: No. only one row per connextion. that's why i decided to add the accepted field @AndriyM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ON` clause is similar to a `WHERE` clause in that both accept a (simple or complex) *condition*, which is a *boolean* expression. The `OR` operator is a *boolean* operator, therefore it can be used in `ON` just as well as in `WHERE`, so feel free to use `OR` any way you like in a join condition to build one that satisfies your requirements.

I think you are basically on the right track with your query. I would just like to point out a couple of things you might be missing simply because you were, perhaps, concentrated on something else at the moment.

One thing is the type of the join. I expect your `friends` table is supposed to contain all the existing links between various users, not only those between the user `5` and anyone else. Therefore, if you join `friends` to `posts` with a *left* join (which is an outer join), you will get *all* the links from `friends`, not only user `5`'s, which is probably not what you want. Of course, you could add a `WHERE` clause with a condition like `friends.id IS NOT NULL`, but that would essentially be equivalent to an *inner* join *without* that condition. So, use an inner join instead.

However, what your `WHERE` clause *may* be needed for is the `friends.acepted = 1` condition, of course, because you want only user 5's friends to be involved and I assume you mean those that are *confirmed* to be friends, thus `acepted` should be `1`.

Of course, there must be a condition for the user `5` somewhere too. It seems to me, it would be easiest if you derived a table from `friends` that would represent *only* the friends of user `5`, and them as a single column too. (That is, both filters would be applied to the derived table instead of to the result set of the join.) That way it would be easier to join the friends to the `posts` table, because your join condition would be simpler. Here's one way how you could derive such a table:

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE followerid WHEN 5 THEN followingid ELSE followerid END AS friend_id
FROM friends
WHERE acepted = 1
  AND (followerid  = 5 OR followingid = 5)
```

That is, this query retrieves user IDs that are friends (`acepted = 1`) of the user `5` (`followerid  = 5 OR followingid = 5`). The single user ID column, `friend_id`, is made of either `followerid` or `followingid`: if one is `5`, the other is pulled, or vice versa.

And this is how you could use this derived table in your final query:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  f.id  /* there's an `id` column in `posts`, so it might be a good idea
           to assign `friends.id` a distinct alias, like `friends_id` */
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    CASE followerid WHEN 5 THEN followingid ELSE followerid END AS friend_id
  FROM friends
  WHERE acepted = 1
    AND (followerid  = 5 OR followingid = 5)
) AS f
  INNER JOIN posts AS p ON p.id_user = f.friend_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your very elaborated answer, will try and let you know

Comment: Unknown column 'p.user_id' in 'on clause'    any idea?

Comment: Should be `p.id_user`, I just messed up the column name, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with a union

```
SELECT posts.*,friends.id FROM friends LEFT JOIN posts ON 
(friends.followerid  = posts.id) where friends.acepted = 1 and posts.id_user = 5
UNION
SELECT posts.*,friends.id FROM friends LEFT JOIN posts ON 
(friends.following.id = posts.id) where friends.acepted = 1 and posts.id_user = 5
```

Comment: so the and for acepted = 1 goes inside each select with where??

Comment: @Toni - in my example, yes - both that clause, and the user id you're selecting would go with each select.

Comment: I jumps this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON (friends.followerid = posts.id) where friends.acepted = 1 and ' at line 2

Comment: Still fails. acepted is a field of friends, i think in the query makes refference to the posts (wich doesn't have that field)

Comment: @Toni: I think I had a spelling error (well, misspelled from the misspelled field to begin with)...shouldn't need to qualify acepted, but I did anyway now.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work:

```
SELECT posts.*, friends.id 
FROM friends LEFT JOIN
     posts
     ON (friends.followerid  = posts.id) OR
        (friends.following.id = posts.id)
```

However, "or"s in "on" statements are usually inefficient.  For instance, they wreak havoc on the use of indexes.  Do note that this method will produce multiple rows for each post, when there are followers and following.

An alternative formulation is to put both on the same line:

```
SELECT posts.*, follower.id, following.id 
FROM posts left outer join
     friends follower
     ON follower.followerid = posts.id left outer join
     friends following
     on following.followingid = posts.id
where follower.id = 5 or following.id = 5
```

Comment: Your query did not return any results